# StopCapture não é destruido corretamente. WebCan travada em execução

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma rotina simples em Delphi que chama a Webcam do dispositivo para tirar fotos dentro do sistema.

O codigo, funciona bem na primeira execução,porém ao fechar a tela não é possivel fazer outra chamada, sendo que webcam permane com led acesso sinalizando uso. **Fiz alguns testes e percebi que tem algo que não é destruido no processo, **mas não consegui achar ainda**.**
Codigo feito no Delphi 10.3.
O travamento ocorre no `TFFotoProdutos.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);`
na linha do `VideoCamera.StopCapture;`

Segue um pedaço do codigo:

```
procedure TFFotoProdutos.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    VideoCamera:= TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultVideoCaptureDevice;
    VideoCamera.OnSampleBufferReady := SampleBufferReady;
    VideoCamera.StartCapture;
end;

procedure TFFotoProdutos.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if VideoCamera <> nil then
    VideoCamera.StopCapture;

    TThread.CurrentThread.Destroy;

end;

procedure TFFotoProdutos.ImageViewer1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     VideoCamera.StopCapture;
end;

procedure TFFotoProdutos.ImageViewer3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    VideoCamera.StartCapture;
end;

procedure TFFotoProdutos.SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
  const ATime: TMediaTime);
begin
    TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, SampleBufferSync);
end;

procedure TFFotoProdutos.SampleBufferSync;
begin
     VideoCamera.SampleBufferToBitmap(Image.Bitmap,true);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema tirando o evento `FormDestroy` do jogo e passando o comando para um  objeto TimageViewer do Form.
Nesse objeto o mesmo comando funciona normalmente.

```
procedure TFFotoProdutos.ImageViewer1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
      if VideoCamera <> nil then
      VideoCamera.StopCapture;
      close;
end;
```